# ffmpeg - cannot fade to white in x264

Tags: video, ffmpeg, x264

I have a directory full of images that I am converting into a video using ffmpeg.

The first frame is a black title frame that fades/morphs into the first video frame, with a 5-frame morph.

I do the mirror image of that at the end of the video, morphing from the last video frame to a  100% white frame again using a 5-frame morph.

I can look at the frames (png files) and they are correct.

But when I generate a video, the fade-in looks fine, but at the end it abruptly cuts from video frame to white, no fade. Is this a compression issue? Something else?

This is the command I use..

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -movflags faststart /tmp/out.mp4
```

And here is the ffmpeg output:

```
    ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 18 2014 12:58:38 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/lib/ffmpeg --extra-cflags=-I/lib/ffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/lib/ffmpeg/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 67.100 / 52. 67.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.533367, bitrate: 104857 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 104857 kb/s, 29.17 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 LZCNT
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=24 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/3113866936.9fXLvm/3113866936.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.34.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], q=-1--1, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg1video -> libx264)
[mp4 @ 0x21adfa0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the filerop=39
frame= 1045 fps=253 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1678kB time=00:00:41.72 bitrate= 329.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=41
video:1666kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.734772%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] frame I:6     Avg QP:13.20  size: 28432
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] frame P:359   Avg QP:19.17  size:  4154
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] frame B:680   Avg QP:13.98  size:    64
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] consecutive B-frames: 12.5%  1.3%  2.3% 83.8%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] mb I  I16..4: 56.3% 34.5%  9.2%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] mb P  I16..4:  2.6%  4.4%  0.7%  P16..4: 11.3%  2.4%  1.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:77.2%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.3%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 0.2%  skip:96.9%  L0:26.2% L1:71.8% BI: 1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] 8x8 transform intra:48.6% inter:82.7%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 47.1% 49.5% 21.3% inter: 3.2% 3.9% 0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] i16 v,h,dc,p: 74% 15%  7%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 25% 22%  3%  4%  3%  6%  4%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 27% 12%  3%  4%  4%  6%  3%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] i8c dc,h,v,p: 55% 22% 19%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] Weighted P-Frames: Y:20.3% UV:20.1%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] ref P L0: 59.8% 17.6% 19.7%  2.7%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] ref B L0: 66.1% 29.0%  4.9%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] ref B L1: 94.4%  5.6%
[libx264 @ 0x21af120] kb/s:326.42
```

Comment: Please show the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my question to include the output. I'm still stumped by it :/

Comment: Slightly more info... Happens even if I create as mpeg:
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -pix_fmt yuv420p -q:v 0 out.mpg

There is simply no white frames (even though the last frame is all white and the preceeding 5 fade into it)

If I remove the yuv420p, I get white frames but no fade..

Comment: Ok, this is crazy, but... If I remove the final frame -- the all white PNG -- but keep the previous 5 frames (which fade into the white frame), the video renders with the fade properly. I only see this problem when the final frame is the full-white image. 

I recently checked and the resolution is correct. I simply cannot explain this.